# How to cache storage in web extensions?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a web extension that uses `browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived()` to call a function on every request. The function also needs to access some settings which I get from `browser.storage.local`.

Currently I fetch those settings on every request. However, requests usually come in bursts when all the data for a new page is loaded. During those bursts, the settings don't change, so it is really not necessary to fetches a fresh copy every time. To minimize the performance impact of my extension I would like to have some kind of cache.

Are there any established approaches for caching data across event handlers in web extensions? The [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts#record_state_changes) explicitly warn not to use global variables and to always use `browser.storage` instead. Or is `browser.storage` fast enough to fetch the same data a few hundred times per second without a significant impact?

Comment: Measure the performance and use [caching](/a/73090402) if there's a noticeable difference.